# Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 446

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Please it's my first Kotlin program I use Intellig IDEA and my operating system is Fedora 27.
Please be patient with me because I'm beginner in Kotlin and Fedora.

my code is

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){

    print("Hosoa")
}
```

and the error which I get it's

```
<Exception from standalone Kotlin compiler>
Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 446
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(ClassReader.java:2464)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:2525)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:761)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:646)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:507)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.modules.JavaModuleInfo$Companion.read(JavaModuleInfo.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.access$findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:148)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:108)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:132)
    at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.ensureItemIterator(Sequences.kt:253)
    at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:240)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.none(_Sequences.kt:1239)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.addModularRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:227)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.computeRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.convertClasspathRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:223)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:401)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:282)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createEnvironmentWithScriptingSupport(K2JVMCompiler.kt:272)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:151)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:380)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:892)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:891)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:378)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you on? This issue was fixed for me when I upgraded Kotlin to the latest (1.2.31).

Answer (score 2):

i hit this issue too , my current java version is 1.9 and 10,When i modify 1.9 to 1.8 this issue is not appear.
[this is my setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMSOW.png)